# Define frequencies present in the time-frequency spectrum using scipy.signal.cwt

Tags: wavelet, cwt

I have a very basic question, but I didn't find a definite answer elsewhere.
When we use [`scipy.signal.cwt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html#scipy.signal.cwt) we specify only one parameter `widths`. Do you know a function that can help to relate this `widths` parameter to frequencies? Like, `pywt.scale2frequency()` to relate scales to frequencies in pywt package.
The only hint I found is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet2.html

```
freq = np.linspace(1, fs/2, 100)
widths = w*fs / (2*freq*np.pi)
```

Can you please explain how this works?

Similar questions, but there was no definite answer:
[Continuous Wavelet Transform with Scipy.signal: what is parameter "widths" in cwt() function? How do time-frequency?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15358/continuous-wavelet-transform-with-scipy-signal-what-is-parameter-widths-in-cw)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813512/continuous-wavelet-transform-with-scipy-signal-python-what-is-parameter-widt

Comment: scipy's CWT is not very developed.  I'd use a different package specifically designed for it.

Answer (score 1):

The center frequency at `scale=1` is `w`, which defaults to `5`. Then for any other `scale` (cwt's `width`) the frequency is `w / scale`, i.e. `w / widths`.

However, PyWavelets' cwt is [flawed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70642/50076), and scipy's even more so; I recommend [ssqueezepy.cwt](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/_cwt.py).