# How to get frequency axsis from pythnon CWT

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform

I did the cwt on a chirp signal :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = 5
n = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False)
f0 = 1
f1 = 10
y = chirp(t, f0, T, f1, method='logarithmic')

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.xlabel('t (seconds)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Sinusoid with varying frequencies from 1-10 Hz]

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

widths = np.arange(1,100) #wavelet widths
cwtmatr = signal.cwt(y, signal.ricker, widths)

plt.pcolormesh(t,widths,cwtmatr,shading='auto',cmap='jet')
```

[image: output from cwt]

As you can see I get time values on x-axis. However, I get width values on y-axis . How can I convert the width values to the corresponding wavelet frequencies ?

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/75796/50076), apply answer to `signal.ricker` (compute center freq for `width=1` instead of using `5`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks for responding, but I didn't really get your answer. Do you mean that the frequency corrseponding to the width of 1 is 5hz ? But what if my signal is consisted of the frequencies which are lower than 5 ?